# SharePoint Document Set not populating Word Template Quick Parts Document Properties

Tags: document-set, word, template, quick-parts

We have a Visual Studio 2010 deployment solution that defines document Library linked to a Document Set. The document Set allows several content types to be uploaded; two of which reference.docx word templates.
Both the .docx word templates reference a number of Quick Parts document properties to pick up values from the document library. The intention being to generate word documents pre-populated with document library item values when clicking the New Document in the Document Set. But in any document produced, the Quick Parts Document Properties are always blank (both in the document Panel and in the body of the Template Document itself. However if the document is saved (in the Document Set) and reopened the document Panel properties become populated although the property tags in the body are still blank. 
So the question is why aren’t the values being pre-populated? One thing I’m not certain about is that when I view the Document Set properties in SharePoint (see below) there are no shared field specified even though they are specified in the schema and I wondered if that was symptomatic of the problem. Be grateful for any advice on this.

[image]

[image]